# Layouts for different screen sizes

Tags: android

I was trying to create different layouts for different screen sizes with swXXXdp layout files. Unfortunately I still can't separate 5,0" from 6,3" as visible on attached image.
Both sizes still use the same file: layout-sw412dp. Any idea for this?

[image: screen sizes]

Comment: IMHO, you should not need separate layouts for that small of a difference in screen size. Focus instead on creating layouts that are more adaptable to small changes in screen size.

Comment: switching from 5" to 6,3" results in a lot of "new" area on the bottom of the screen, I have no idea how to make elements on constraintLayout change theirs place depending on screen resolution (if that's even possible)

Comment: "switching from 5" to 6,3" results in a lot of "new" area on the bottom of the screen," -- so? Resizing a desktop browser window results in a lot of "new" area on the bottom of the window. Developers do not create individual Web pages, or even individual sets of CSS rules, for each browser window size. "I have no idea how to make elements on constraintLayout change theirs place" -- perhaps you should ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] showing your layout, your results, and asking how to make changes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you yo use Constraint Layout, maybe it could be useful for your goal...

> ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

[doc](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)